# Incorrect File Download using mechanize response in Perl

Tags: perl, download, mechanize

I created a script which access a URL with basic authentication. Once I've passed the credentials, it will download the file in my local folder. The problem is I got an incorrect filename. Here's my sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                             

use strict;                                                                     
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;                                                                    
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $url = "http://sampleurl.com";
my $dir = 'C:\\pl';
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();         
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());                              
$mech ->credentials("sampleurl.com:80", "sampleurl.com", "username",  "password");                       
$mech->get($url);
my $res = $mech->res();
if($res->is_success){
    my $filename = $res->filename();
    print $filename;             
    $mech->save_content( $dir.'\\'.$filename, binmode => ':raw', decoded_by_headers => 1 );
    print $mech->status;
}else{
    print "Error";

}

exit 0;
```

Instead of downloading sample_url.DOC, it only downloaded sample with no file extension. can you help with my problem? I want to download the whole file.

Comment: Are you certain the file has no extension, and that Windows isn't just hiding the extension from you in its GUI file viewer.  (That's it default behavior.)  Have you tried looking at the file on the command line using the `dir` command?

Comment: Try to print ``$res`` by doing this: ``use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($res)`` This will allow you to see the request sent and the response, as well as the whole data structure inside ``$res`` it should show you what was received

Comment: In the doc for HTTP::Response the method filename gives that the string returned is derived in the following order: 1) From the header Content-Disposition 2) From the header Content-Location 3) From the URI used to request. Either do as @nrathaus suggests or inspect the HTTP headers with ie FireBug or Wireshark to find out what the webserver returns for the Mechanize object

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that `$res->filename();` will produce a file extension or anything at all for that matter. The page you're currently reading doesn't have a filename extension for example.

You will have to guess a filename extension from the media type.

```
use MIME::Types qw(by_mediatype);
```

...

```
my $filename = $r->filename();
if(!$filename) { $filename = 'untitled'; }

if($filename !~ /\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}$/) {
    my $type = $res->header('Content-Type');
    my $ext = 'txt';

    if($type) {
        my @types = by_mediatype($type);

        if($#types > -1) {
            $ext = $types[0][0];
        }
    }

    $filename .= '.' . $ext;
}

print $filename;
```